# Xtext, Declaring array and structure types

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, xtend

I want to make a Dsl that allow to declare Arrays and structures. I can do it with this grammar:

```
Set:
    'SET' '(' attribute=ID ',' value=AttributeValue ')';
SimpleValue:
    INT | STRING;

Structure:
    '{' ID ':' AttributeValue (',' ID ':' AttributeValue)* '}';

Array:
    '[' AttributeValue (',' AttributeValue)* ']' ;

AttributeValue:
    SimpleValue |
    Structure |
    Array 
;
```

However, in my interpreter, I can't figure the type of my variables.  can't do something like :

```
if( s.value instanceof Array) {val Array array = s.value}
```

I tried with this grammar:

```
SimpleValue:
    {SimpleValue}
     INT | STRING
;

Structure:
    '{' ID ':' var0=SimpleValue (',' ID ':' var1=SimpleValue)* '}'
;

Array: 
    '[' var0=SimpleValue(',' var1=SimpleValue)* ']' 
;

AttributeValue : 
    SimpleValue |
    Structure |
    Array 
;
```

but it doesn't work. In the line

```
if( s.value instanceof Array) {val Array array = s.value}
```

`s.value` is red with "`Type mismatch: cannot convert from AttributeValue to Array"` error

Answer (score 0):

why dont you assign the array values?

```
Array: '[' values+=AttributeValue (',' values+=AttributeValue)* ']' ;
```

and do something similar inside structure?

```
Structure: '{' values+=StructureValue (',' values+=StructureValue)* '}';
StructureValue: name=ID ':' value=AttributeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a pure Xtend problem and has nothing to do with Xtext.

`s.value` is a getter call. Even if the result of the first call (in the `instanceof`) is an instance of `Array`, the type system can't guarantee that the second call (on the right side of the assignment) will also return an `Array` instance.

The solution is to extract a local variable:

```
val value = s.value
if( value instanceof Array) {val Array array = value}
```

Although the assignment then becomes unnecessary.